# How to optimize reading and comparing lines between multiple files?

Tags: python

What will be the best way to make reading the files more efficient? Using this

```
    with open(fname, 'r') as myf:
        for myline in myf:
```

or

```
    for glob.glob('*.txt'):
```

I performed a `cprofile` stats and this is what I got for a few sorted lines:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      4/1    0.000    0.000 1895.428 1895.428 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1  157.201  157.201 1895.428 1895.428 runmyfiles.py:2(<module>)
        5 1365.371  273.074 1554.015  310.803 runmyfiles.py:9(readFile)
    52727  184.205    0.003  184.205    0.003 {method 'write' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
   194515    0.300    0.000   74.091    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.6/re.py:214(findall)
   194515   72.479    0.000   72.479    0.000 {method 'findall' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
```

I know I should optimize the file reading process but not sure how to go about it. I may need to open all the files at once and compare each line in each file with similar lines in the other files then write the output for the line containing the max value of bb. Is this logical considering the stats generated?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also, your code is incomplete, as `parse_file` does not appear in the supplied code.

Comment: parse-file is readFile. My code is complete and using a lot of memory. I need to reduce the usage due to the large file sizes I am working with

Comment: Your code is **not** complete. It will not run as written: `NameError: name 'f_step' is not defined`. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: it is now complete and runs. I had an error which I have fixed

Comment: It looks like you want the line from each file which contains the largest value for BB=(number)? Or just single largest value?

Comment: yes I want from each file. i.e compare lines containing values of bb and select the highest value of bb. Then write out each line with the max value of bb into the output text after comparison. i.e compare lines 1 file 1 with line 1 file 2 with line 1 file 3 etc and whichever line has the highest value of bb gets written to output, then go to line 2 etc

Comment: I am wondering if I asked the right question because I am not getting any answers. Or is it too trivial? I am still stuck here. My code works but I need it to be more efficient.

Comment: If your code works without errors, a better place to ask could be [codereview.se].